# Is there a php template engine can work like asp.net

Tags: php, templates, templating-engine

PHP template engine like smart only gives an extends method for us to designing pages. In asp.net, we can extend(using master page) and also can create user controls and include different user controls in one page. Is there a PHP template engine can do such work?

Comment: PHP IS a templating engine, which is why you can mix HTML and PHP in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the Smarty http://www.smarty.net

Answer (score 0):

A very good and modern template engine for php is [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)